How do I find the Key Vault that is used to managed the keys of a storage account
I have a storage account that the keys are managed and periodically rotated by a key Vault. Now I have to generate a SAS token for a particular blob directory but because the keys are rotated automatically, my SAS token expires took quickly because the key that was used to sign it has been rotated.
My question is how do I find the key vault resource that manages keys of the storage account(I didn't set the autorotation/regeneration up), so I can maybe create a SAS definition or something.
I am open to other suggestions to solve this issue. I don't see any command to get this attribute or properties from the storage account in the docs.

Please edit to show your work. As written, you presented a requirement, but no code or any other details. Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve]

@DavidMakogon 1/1 I asked a straight forward scenario question. There is no “work” or “code” to present. I am in search of the az powershell or az cli command to get the properties of a storage account that shows keyvault that rotates primary and secondary keys.  I appreciate that the responders understood to a certain degree and attempted to help but the solution points to a different property which is customer managed key CMK. I have a ticket open with Microsoft for this issue I posted here and hoped if any chance I missed something in the doc. However, I will review my question  to improve

More so I ran get-azstorageaccount for the storage account in question and gone through all the props of the object returned and I don’t have any property that holds a keyvault value.


How do I find the Key Vault that is used to managed the keys of a storage account?

You can get the key vault that is used to managed the keys of a storage account using Azure CLI command also.
Command.
storageAccountName="venkat7891"
resourceGroupName="zzzz"
az storage account show --name $storageAccountName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query encryption.keyVaultProperties

Command and output:
az storage account show --name $storageAccountName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query encryption.keyVaultProperties
{
  "currentVersionedKeyExpirationTimestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
  "currentVersionedKeyIdentifier": "https://keyvaultvenkat326.vault.azure.net/keys/key1/d6246xxxxxxa6",
  "keyName": "key1",
  "keyVaultUri": "https://keyvaultvenkat326.vault.azure.net",
  "keyVersion": "",
  "lastKeyRotationTimestamp": "2024-08-13T04:01:14.411477+00:00"
}


To get the keyvault name and key name as same as you can use the below command.
keyVaultName=$(az storage account show --name $storageAccountName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query "encryption.keyVaultProperties.keyVaultUri" -o tsv | awk -F[/:] '{print $4}')
keyName=$(az storage account show --name $storageAccountName --resource-group $resourceGroupName --query "encryption.keyVaultProperties.keyName" -o tsv)

echo "Key Vault Name: $keyVaultName"
echo "Key Name: $keyName"
Key Vault Name: keyvaultvenkat326.vault.azure.net
Key Name: key1


Reference:
az storage account | Microsoft Learn

not encryption keys, but storage account keys. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/overview-storage-keys

The OP has only published a requirement, and then left everything to the Community. Stack Overflow isn't the place for custom code requests. Please just close-vote, and post a comment to help the OP improve their question - your answer will likely disappear, as this question will likely be closed and deleted shortly. Also: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

This is not a custom code request. I presented a scenario and hoped to get a direction or documentation to follow. Alleging that I left it to community even when I responded to the answer with the specific attribute of the storage account ( key rotation key vault) I hope to access in the storage account object, is inappropriate and unfair. I also responded with a link to show the implementation of the Keyvault Managed Storage Account setup that was configured on the storage account with a keyvault resource property that I hope to retrieve.
